# load nhibernate.dll assembly manually

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, dll

I have a small asp.net webapi application with simple plugin system.
All plugins located at "/bin/debug/plugins/" folder.
I load plugins at application start and register components from plugins in autofac container.

But i have a problem with nhibernate plugin, that contains my repositories, mappings etc. After plugin loading nhibernate.dll loaded too (check it with ProcessExporer: http://postimg.org/image/mm4w56vln/). Then i try to create ISessionFactory... and receive next error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate, Version=4.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"NHibernate, Version=4.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4
```

My plugin loader:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Jarres.Plugin.Exceptions;

namespace Jarres.Plugin
{
    public class PluginLoader : IPluginLoader
    {
        private readonly List<Assembly> _cache = new List<Assembly>();

        public IDictionary<PluginInfo, IPlugin> Load(IEnumerable<PluginInfo> plugins)
        {
            if (plugins == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plugins");
            }

            InitializeCache();

            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveModuleAssembly;
            var result = plugins.ToDictionary(x => x, GetPlugin);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= ResolveModuleAssembly;

            return result;
        }

        private IPlugin GetPlugin(PluginInfo plugin)
        {
            var path    = plugin.Path;
            var name    = plugin.Name;
            var version = plugin.Version;

            var fileversion = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(path).ProductVersion;
            if (version != fileversion)
            {
                throw new PluginVersionException(name, version, fileversion);
            }

            var types = LoadAssembly(path).GetExportedTypes().Where(x => typeof (IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(x) && !x.IsAbstract).ToArray();
            if (types.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new PluginNotFoundException(name, path);
            }
            if (types.Length > 1)
            {
                throw new MultiplePluginsException(name, path);
            }

            return (IPlugin)Activator.CreateInstance(types[0]);             
        }

        private Assembly LoadAssembly(string path)
        {
            var assembly = GetFromCacheByPath(path);

            if (assembly == null)
            {
                assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(path);
                AddToCache(assembly);
                LoadAssemblyReferences(assembly);
            }

            return assembly;
        }

        private void LoadAssemblyReferences(Assembly assembly)
        {
            foreach (var reference in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);

                if (directory != null)
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(directory, reference.Name + ".dll");
                    if (File.Exists(path))
                    {
                        LoadAssembly(path);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private Assembly ResolveModuleAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
        {
            return GetFromCacheByName(args.Name);
        }


        #region cache

        private void InitializeCache()
        {
            _cache.AddRange(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
            foreach (var assembly in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                _cache.Add(Assembly.Load(assembly));
            }
        }

        private void AddToCache(Assembly assembly)
        {
            if (assembly == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("assembly");
            }

            _cache.Add(assembly);
        }

        private Assembly GetFromCacheByPath(string path)
        {
            var name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
            return _cache.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetName().Name == Path.GetFileName(name));
        }

        private Assembly GetFromCacheByName(string name)
        {
            return _cache.FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName.StartsWith(name));
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

And i can create ISessionFactory only if nhibernate.dll copied to /bin/debug/ folder. But i want store this dll in plugin folder.
For example, i have't any problems with entity framework plugin.

Why i can't create ISessionFactory when nhibernate.dll loaded?

Comment: What error do you get? Could you append it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
All references load correctly, but this references located not in /bin/{Debug, Release}/ folder. 
So, i add path to target folder to my app.config as .

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are lacking a dependency. Spot it with [fusion logger. (This is a link to a SO question on how to use it.)](/q/255669/1178314)